# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists when I use Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to test my code on the multi-nodes using Apache Spark.
Before testing it, I already found that my codes worked well on my local mode.
And then, I made the Jar file using maven and run it with a shell script but got the error below.

```
 17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170619035958-0003/1 is now RUNNING
17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170619035958-0003/0 is now RUNNING
17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170619035958-0003/2 is now RUNNING
17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170619035958-0003/3 is now RUNNING
17/06/19 03:59:59 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
        at SparkPinkMST.DataSplitter.createPartitionFiles(DataSplitter.java:243)
        at SparkPinkMST.Pink.main(Pink.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 11 more
```

After got the above error, I googled and added the google guava dependency in my `pom.xml`. But the result was same. My problem is that the error only occur on the multi-nodes on the Spark platform.
How to resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have HDFS? If so, keep it on HDFS and give that jar during spark-submit using --jars.

Comment: @morfious902002 Okay. I will try it. Thanks for your quick reply.